# Discord.net print all user roles

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I've been working on a Discord bot and am trying to print every role the user has. I keep getting the "Discord.CollectionWrapper`1[Discord.WebSocket.SocketRole]" error and can't seem to fix it. Is there a way I can get it to show all the users role?

````
        {
            if (!Context.Message.MentionedUsers.Any())
            {
                await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Can't give you any information if you don't specify a member");
            }

            var user = Context.Message.MentionedUsers.First();
            SocketGuildUser U = (SocketGuildUser)Context.Message.MentionedUsers.First();
            var GuildUser = Context.Guild.GetUser(Context.User.Id);
            var typingChannel = Context.Channel;
            await typingChannel.TriggerTypingAsync();




            EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder()
            {
                Title = "Hello world!",
                Description = "I am a description set by initializer.",
            };
            eb.AddField("ID:", $"{user.Id}")
                .WithAuthor(Context.Client.CurrentUser)
                .WithColor(Color.DarkPurple)
                .WithTitle($"***{user.Username}***")
                .WithDescription($"{user.Username}#{user.Discriminator} \n status: {user.Status}\n Account created at date: {user.CreatedAt}\nJoined at: {U.JoinedAt}" +
                $"\nRoles: {U.Roles.ToString()}\n Permissions: {U.GuildPermissions}\n")
                .WithCurrentTimestamp()
                .Build();

            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, eb.Build());
        }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Discord.CollectionWrapper`1[Discord.WebSocket.SocketRole]"

That's not an error - that's the output of the default `ToString()` implementation. Very few classes actually override `Object.ToString()`.

Use Linq's `.Select` and `String.Join` to get each value instead:

```
String.Join( separator: ", ", values: U.Roles.Select( r => r.ToString() ) )
```

Like so:

```
$"\nRoles: { String.Join( separator: ", ", values: U.Roles.Select( r => r.ToString() ) ) }"
```